# resize iframe to fit mobile browser in joomla

Tags: mobile, iframe, joomla

how do I code an iframe in joomla to fit a mobile browser width? I have a few iframes loaded in articles but when i view them on a mobile device they are full size instead of resized to fit.

Comment: Have you tried any CSS code of your own?

Comment: yes i have the iframe resizing, in general for my browser width by using width:95%; but it doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: That is most likely because the content inside has a set width and therefore forcing the change. You need to ensure that the content inside has a fluid width too

Comment: what if the content inside the iframe is from an outside source.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the content is coming from, it matters what styles are being applied to it. Let say your iframe is set to 95% and you have a form inside which is set to 700px, due to this, it will overlap the edge of the container and therefore not be responsive

Comment: i see what you are saying ;)

Comment: If you could provide the html code and css for the iframe and the content inside, it will be easier to provide a more accurate solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried also many different css based or javascript based solutions. Finally I ended up with the [iframe resizer script](http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/) which can be used standalone or as jQuery plugin which worked awesome. You can even include a second script in the iframe content which will report back if it has changed that the iframe get adapted in height and width.

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(JURI::base() . 'components/com_demo/libraries/iframe-resizer/jquery.iframeResizer.min.js');
$doc->addScriptDeclaration("jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('iframe').iFrameResize({log: true});
});");

echo '<iframe src="my_url"></iframe>';
```

Comment: thanks, where would i put this in my joomla site? (sorry I am kind of a beginner but pretty good at figuring things out)